# Can a robot not implementing Robot Exclusion Protocal (robots.txt) read any content of a website?

Tags: web, robots.txt

The [Robot Exclusion document](http://www.robotstxt.org/orig.html) says:

*It is not enforced by anybody, and there no guarantee that all current and future robots will use it. Consider it a common facility the majority of robot authors offer the WWW community to protect WWW server against unwanted accesses by their robots.*

Is that mean a BAD robot, not implementing Robot Exclusion Protocal (robots.txt) , can read any content of a website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This protocol is a means to mark up portions of a site which it makes no sense to crawl for robots. It is not a security facility.

Which is to say, any sensitive or private information served up by a web site should be available only within an authenticated session. It is not enough to use a URL-based-on-GUID-with-no-links-to-it or robots.txt to protect such data.

There were some embarrassing incidents, e.g. when a search engine unintentionally indexed (and cached) Send SMS confirmation pages of a cellphone provider, altogether with SMS texts and phone numbers of recipients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. No robot is forced to follow the rules.